# Switching the html page from the MainPage.xaml.cs of a phonegap application

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, cordova

In my windows 8 version of my phonegap application I am trying to use an application bar to switch to certain pages. The following code will not form a valid URI to navigate to. If anyone has a work around or way to make this particular code work it would be appreciated.

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (button.Text == "Logout")
        {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("UserName");
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("Password");
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/www/index.html", UriKind.Absolute)); 
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string esfjdlkfj; //placeholder
    }

}
```

Comment: The UriKind is actually Relative I was messing with the code before posting this

Comment: have you managed to find a solution, i am running into the same problem....

Answer (score 1):

you can use [invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  to call  if are using jquery mobile

```
$.mobile.changePage("index.html", {transition : "none" });
```